# Composing lit template using a dynamic class

Tags: lit-element, lit

Is there a way of composing a template in Lit using a dynamically derived Lit Element?

I'm talking something like this:

```js
import { chooseCorrectComponent } from "./chooseCorrectComponent.js";
let myLitElement = chooseCorrectComponent(arguments);

render () {
    return html`
        ${new myLitElement(propsGoHerePerhaps)}
    `
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was easier than I thought.

```js
function chooseCorrectCoupon(arg) {
    if(arg === "foo") {
        return new MyLitElementA();
    } else {
        return new MyLitElementB();
    }
}



render () {
    let myLitElement = chooseCorrectComponent("bar");
    myLitElement.propA = 123;
    myLitElement.propB = "hello";

    return html`
        ${myLitElement}
    `
}
```